# Hunchentoot dispatcher

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I'm relatively new to Common Lisp (SBCL) and Hunchentoot (using Quicklisp). Can someone tell me how I can get this to work? I'm trying to wrap an Hunchentoot server and some paths in a function as a unit. When I run this, only Hunchentoot's index page is available, the paths /a and /b aren't.

```
(defun app0 (port)
  (let ((*dispatch-table* nil) (server (make-instance 'hunchentoot:acceptor :port port)))
    (push (hunchentoot:create-prefix-dispatcher "/a" (lambda () "a")) *dispatch-table*)
    (push (hunchentoot:create-prefix-dispatcher "/b" (lambda () "b")) *dispatch-table*)
    (hunchentoot:start server) server))
```

Comment: `*dispatch-table*`is already a global variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems, as far as I can see. First, request handling via `*dispatch-table*` requires, that the acceptor is of type `easy-acceptor`, i.e., you will have to

```
(make-instance 'easy-acceptor ...)
```

The [documentation](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#request-dispatch) has the details.

The second problem is, that you rebind the `*dispatch-table*` during the set-up code, and push new values into this binding. Since the binding is reverted after the `let` is finished (and since `hunchentoot:start` works asynchronously), your entries in the `*dispatch-table*` are effectively lost, when the server is running. Try

```
(push (hunchentoot:create-prefix-dispatcher "/a" (lambda () "a")) *dispatch-table*)
(push (hunchentoot:create-prefix-dispatcher "/b" (lambda () "b")) *dispatch-table*)
```

at the top-level (or do something like that in a dedicated set-up function). If you don't like the global `*dispatch-table*` approach, you can also create a subclass of `acceptor`, and override `acceptor-dispatch-request` (and thus, implement any kind of dispatch you like).

Just as a side-note: you do not prefix `*dispatch-table*`, while you prefix virtually any other symbol from `hunchentoot`'s package. Is this just a copy/paste mistake, or is this also the case in your actual code? If you do not `:use` the `hunchentoot` package in wherever package your code happens to live, then you'd also have to qualify the dispatch table as `hunchentoot:*dispatch-table*`.

**Edit** (to address the question in the comment section) There is an [example in the hunchentoot documentation](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#subclassing-acceptors), which seems to do exactly what you want to do:

```
(defclass vhost (tbnl:acceptor)
  ((dispatch-table
    :initform '()
    :accessor dispatch-table
    :documentation "List of dispatch functions"))
  (:default-initargs  
   :address "127.0.0.1"))

(defmethod tbnl:acceptor-dispatch-request ((vhost vhost) request)
  (mapc (lambda (dispatcher)
      (let ((handler (funcall dispatcher request)))
        (when handler
          (return-from tbnl:acceptor-dispatch-request (funcall handler)))))
    (dispatch-table vhost))
  (call-next-method))

(defvar vhost1 (make-instance 'vhost :port 50001))
(defvar vhost2 (make-instance 'vhost :port 50002))

(push
 (tbnl:create-prefix-dispatcher "/foo" 'foo1)
 (dispatch-table vhost1))
(push
 (tbnl:create-prefix-dispatcher "/foo" 'foo2)
 (dispatch-table vhost2))

(defun foo1 () "Hello")
(defun foo2 () "Goodbye")

(tbnl:start vhost1)
(tbnl:start vhost2)
```

(comments present in the documentation removed for brevity). The `tbnl` is a predefined nickname for package `hunchentoot`. You can use both interchangeably, though I would recommend, that you pick one and stick to it. Mixing both might generate confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first one/problem was a typo in my code, and I have it set to easy-acceptor, I'll update my post shortly. The second part  really helps to clear up some confusion I did have surrounding bindings and hunchentoot not seeing those routes. I failed to realize the bindings were being reset. Also thank you for the side note, I'm afraid I haven't prefixed *dispatch-table* with the package name.

Comment: I'm not really looking for fancy dispatching so I'd like to avoid subclassing acceptor and in the process introduce errors. What I was hoping to accomplish was to be able to create multiple instances of a server running on different ports with some instance specific data like a db connection. Would you recommend the best way to do that?